# Paillier cryptosystem break with random number

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, randomness, paillier

In the Paillier cryptosystem we choose $n=p\,q$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes, $g=n+1$, $\lambda=\phi(n)$, $\mu=\lambda^{-1}\bmod n$.

The public key is: $(n,g)$.

The private key is: $(\lambda,\mu)$.

Encryption: choose random $r$ ($0<r<n$), encryption of message $m$ is $c=(g^m)(r^n)\bmod n^2$

Decryption: $m=((c^\lambda\bmod n^2-1)/n)\,\mu\bmod n$.

I am asking: is it possible to decrypt the ciphertext of the Paillier cryptosystem with knowledge of the random number $r$?

Comment: Welcome to crypto-SE. I reformatted the question [using MathJax](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). I have _not_ changed to the usual decryption formula: $m=\bigl\lfloor((c^\lambda\bmod n^2)-1)/n\bigr\rfloor\,\mu\bmod n$, nor added the usual additional requirements $p\ne q$ and $p<2q<4p$. You can of course [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/104044/edit) the question, perhaps adding where you are stuck.

Comment: Is that homework? That would make the question off-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) unless effort to solve the problem is shown in the question. For now I'll only give hints: with $r$ known, what remains unknown in the equation $c=(g^m)(r^n)\bmod n^2$ ? Work that out using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) and elementary properties of$\bmod$.

Comment: I've reached this point: c = (nm+1) % (n**2) + (r**n) % (n**2). 
what should i do next?

Comment: First, fix it; where did the second + creep in? Next, try to isolate the one unknown. Hint: almost all integers have a multiplicative inverse modulo $n^2$, and it can be efficiently computed, e.g. by the [(half) extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers). Note: MathJax mostly works in comment too, e.g. $c=(g^m)(r^n)\bmod n^2$ is written `$c=(g^m)(r^n)\bmod n^2$`.

Comment: I would disagree with fgrieu's suggestion of using the binomial theorem - instead, from $(g^m)(r^n) \bmod n^2$ and $r$, first find $g^m \bmod n^2$; once you got there, what can you say about that?

Comment: @poncho: I wrote my [proof using the binomial theorem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/104310/555). I scratch my head for another argument that $(n+1)^m\equiv m\,n+1\bmod{n^2}$, or another proof altogether, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**, it would be possible to decrypt the ciphertext of the Paillier cryptosystem if the random number $r$ leaked.

Encryption if per $c=(g^m)(r^n)\bmod n^2$. We know that $g=n+1$. Thus $c=((n+1)^m)(r^n)\bmod n^2$. By the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem),
$$(n+1)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom n k n^k$$
and $n^k\bmod n^2=0$ when $k>1$. Therefore, $(n+1)^m\bmod n^2$ reduces to $m\,n+1\bmod n^2$, and we get $c=(m\,n+1)(r^n)\bmod n^2$.

Knowing $r$, and $n$ being public, we can computes $s=r^{-1}\bmod n$, e.g. by the [(half) extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers). We can then compute $t=s^n\,c\bmod n^2$ which is such that $t=m\,n+1\bmod n^2$.

And then, since $0\le m<n$, we can compute $m$ as $(t-1)/n$.

---

A [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/236547) asks what if $g$ is a public generator other than $n+1$. We now have $g^m\equiv r^{-n}\,c\pmod{n^2}$ where we can compute the Right Hand Side. That allows at least:

- checking a guess of $m$
- computing $m$ by [Baby Step/Giant Step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) or [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms) for small-enough $m$, e.g. when we can perform about $\mathcal O(\sqrt m)$ modular multiplications modulo $n$ (or modulo $n^2$).

I don't rule out there are better attacks that work for larger $m$.

Comment: Would a similar attack exist given a different choice of (public) $g$?

Comment: @FWDekker: Good question! I expanded the answer, but do not reach a full conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Once you know $r$, you can remove it from the ciphertext. If $c=(1+n)^m\bmod n^2$ then $m=(c-1)/n\mod n.$